# Excel VBA error handler not working for 'run-time error 13: type mismatch'

Tags: vba, excel, error-handling, type-mismatch

I am running the sub below for an Excel file containing about 10 worksheets, each containing a pivottable linked to the same data source.  I have two versions of the 'Market' and 'Region' fields in my data (i.e. 'Market (SC)', 'Market (AN)', 'Region (SC)', 'Region (AN)'), and need to be able to switch between them easily.  I set up the code to first bring the corresponding slicers to the front (they are superimposed so that will hide the other), then loop through each pivottable and swap the other 'Market' and 'Region' fields (maintaining the same position, etc.).

Since I'm using the property ".SourceName" to identify the field, the loop runs into an error when the "Values" PivotField is compared to my string.  I've put in "On Error Goto next_fld" to tell it to skip to the next field when this occurs, but this only works for 8 of the 10 worksheets -- for the other two I get the error "Run-time error '13' Type Mismatch" and the debug screen highlights the " *** " line.  If I use "On Error Resume Next", it assumes that the If statement was True and carries out a lot of unwanted actions (messes up various PivotTables).

I'm self-taught and do not have a complete understanding of the error handler, but from the resources I've come across to fix this error, the handler should be taking care of this (which it does work for 8/10 worksheets).

Here is my code:

```
Sub SwapMktRegFields()

Dim ws As Worksheet, shp As Shape
Dim i As Integer
Dim target As String, repl As String

target = Sheet5.Range("E3").value

 'Identify current field, use other as repl(acement)
Select Case target
     'AN slicers selected
    Case Is = "AN"
        target = "(AN)"
        repl = "(SC)"
        Sheet5.Range("E3").value = "SC"
     'SC slicers selected
    Case Is = "SC"
        target = "(SC)"
        repl = "(AN)"
        Sheet5.Range("E3").value = "AN"
End Select

 'Bring replacement slicers to front (some are in shape groups)
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each shp In ws.Shapes
        Select Case shp.Type
            Case Is = msoGroup
                For i = 1 To shp.GroupItems.Count
                    If shp.GroupItems(i).Name Like "Market " & target & "*" Or shp.GroupItems(i).Name Like "Region " & target & "*" Then shp.GroupItems(i).ZOrder msoSendToBack
                Next i
            Case Else
                If shp.Name Like "Market " & target & "*" Or shp.Name Like "Region " & target & "*" Then shp.ZOrder msoSendToBack
        End Select
    Next shp
Next ws



 'Replace old PivotFields with replacement PivotFields

Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim fld As PivotField
Dim orient As Long, pos As Long

' MY ERROR HANDLER
On Error GoTo next_fld
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each pvt In ws.PivotTables
        For Each fld In pvt.PivotFields
 ' *** ERROR ON NEXT LINE WHEN fld IS 'VALUES'
            If fld.SourceName = "Market " & target And fld.Orientation <> xlHidden Then
                orient = fld.Orientation
                pos = fld.Position
                fld.Orientation = xlHidden
                With pvt.PivotFields("Market " & repl)
                    .Orientation = orient
                    .Position = pos
                End With
            ElseIf fld.SourceName = "Region " & target And fld.Orientation <> xlHidden Then
                orient = fld.Orientation
                pos = fld.Position
                fld.Orientation = xlHidden
                With pvt.PivotFields("Region " & repl)
                    .Orientation = orient
                    .Position = pos
                End With
            End If
next_fld:
        Next fld
    Next pvt
Next ws

 'A custom function to clear filters and re-apply a default
ResetPivotFilters

End Sub
```

The weirdest part is that the error is EXACTLY THE SAME as the other 8 sheets that work with this code.  If I remove the error handler completely, I get the exact same pop-up and line highlighted for the other sheets... Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks

Comment: You don't clear the error in your error handler.  Read this for a good overview of how you should structure your error handling:  http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm

Comment: Completely remove your error handling and tell us what line the error occurs on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim, this was very helpful and answered my question.  I updated the end of my code to the following:

```
ResetPivotFilters

Exit Sub

err_handler:
Resume next_fld

End Sub
```

and updated my error handling enabling line to "On Error Goto err_handler".  Working now.  Thank you!